# how to read text file line by line then parse charaters in a line?

Tags: c++, parsing

I am reading from a text file an infix expression and I want to convert it to postfix expression.

For example this what is in the text file

```
1+1
2+2
```

I am reading the expression one line at a time as follows

```
 char c;
 string readLine; 
ifstream txtfile("a1.txt");
 while ( getline (txtfile,readLine) ) // read line by line
    {
        cout << readLine << endl;

        // how can I set c to be the first character from the read line


         infix_to_postfix(stack, queue,c );

    }
```

My question is how can I let the variable `C` equal the first character from the read line so I can send it to my `infix_to_postfix` function? Then the second character .. all the way to the end of the line.

When the first line is fully read, I want to read the second line and send one character at time to my  `infix_to_postfix` function. I hope I am clear here, thanks!

Comment: Is `readLine` a `char[]` or a `std::string`, or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate characters from `std::string` using a regular `for` loop with an index, like this:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i != readLine.size() ; i++) {
    infix_to_postfix(stack, queue, readLine[i]);
}
```

or using an iterator:

```
for (string::const_iterator p = readLine.begin() ; p != readLine.end() ; ++p) {
    infix_to_postfix(stack, queue, *p);
}
```

There is little, if any, difference between the two snippets in terms of performance, so the choice is up to you.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `get` method for a single character:

```
char c;
std::ifstream txtfile("a1.txt");
while (std::getline(txtfile, readLine))
{
    while (txtfile.get(c))
        infix_to_postfix(stack, queue, c);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `std::stringstream`,

```
#include <sstream>

// insert the following inside the getline loop

std::stringstream ss(ReadLine);

char c;

while (ss >> c) 
    infix_to_postfix(stack, queue, c);
```